# Graphql query results in "Unexpected enum for a scalar" in android using apolloclient

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to fetch some data from API using Graphql with ApolloClient. But it's resulting in as **"Unexpected enum for a scalar"**. Please help me out to solve the error. Below is my code.

ItemsQuery.graphql

```
query fetchCategoryItems($input : String!) {
__typename
items(where: {categoryUuid: {_eq: input}}) {
    categoryUuid
    description
    image
    name
    ..... // some more items
}
```

}

Activity code.

```
val client = ApolloClientInstance.getInstance()
val categoryId = "random_id"
client.query(FetchCategoryItemsQuery.builder().input(categoryId.toString()).build())
        .responseFetcher(ApolloResponseFetchers.NETWORK_FIRST)
        .enqueue(object : ApolloCall.Callback<FetchCategoryItemsQuery.Data>() {
            override fun onFailure(exception: ApolloException) {
                Logger.debug(TAG, "${exception.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(response: Response<FetchCategoryItemsQuery.Data>) {
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "${response.data()?.items()?.size}")
                    Logger.debug(TAG, "error: ${response.errors()[0].message()}")
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a `$` -- your variable is defined as `$input` but you're using it as `input`. Without the `$`, the parser assumes `input` is an enum value instead of a variable.

Comment: I have tried by prefixing `$` as `$input`. It is giving error as **error: variable input of type String! is used in position expecting uuid**

Comment: That's unrelated to your original syntax error. Just change the type of the variable as indicated in the error.

Comment: Thank you  :). It's working now. Lint was showing it as an unknown field so, I was assuming it as an error ;)